# How to Pass MongoDB error to React from Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am Working in a MERN application. In one of my model of express.js I have unique email schema like below

```
email: {
   type: String,
   trim: true,
   required: true,
   minlength: 3,
   unique: true
},
```

I am checking uniqueness of email address when I am saving a record like below

```
address.save()
.then(address => {
   //other code
})
.catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
   res.status(500).json({
     message: 'Error Occured',
         error: err
   });
 });
```

I am getting below error in Terminal.

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: addresses.addresses index: email_1 dup key: { : "nowphp@yahoo.com" }
[0]     at Function.create (/home/foysal/Videos/my-app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:43:12)
[0]     at toError (/home/foysal/Videos/my-app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:149:22)
[0]     at coll.s.topology.insert (/home/foysal/Videos/my-app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/collection_ops.js:859:39)
[0]     at /home/foysal/Videos/my-app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:532:18
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
[0]   driver: true,
[0]   name: 'MongoError',
[0]   index: 0,
[0]   code: 11000,
[0]   errmsg:
[0]    'E11000 duplicate key error collection: addresses.addresses index: email_1 dup key: { : "nowphp@yahoo.com" }',
[0]   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

[image]

I would like to modify this error `errmsg:
'E11000 duplicate key error collection: addresses.addresses index: email_1 dup key: { : "nowphp@yahoo.com" }',` to `Email already Exists` and pass this to React (front end).

How can I do that ?

***UPDATE***

I am using below code in `express.js`

```
address.save()
    .then( address => {
        // others code
    })
    .catch( err => {
        const errString = err.toString();
        if (errString.includes("E11000")) return res.status(404).json({ err: 'That email is already in use!' });
    });
```

My React Redux action is like below

```
export const addAddress = value => dispatch => {
  return Axios.post('/api/address', value)
    .then( response => {
      // other code
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.log('actionError', error )
    });
};
```

I am getting below error in console

`Error: "Request failed with status code 404"`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: Check if the email already exists before creation (better option) or allow Mongo to throw an `error object` during user creation, convert it to a `string` and then check if that `string` includes `E11000`.

**Working example**: https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit (click [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/controllers/user.js#L6-L36) to view the code in use as described below; in addition, the code below refers to a User static method which you can find [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/models/user.js#L18-L26))

---

For example (choose one option, you don’t need both):

```
const createUser = async (req, res, done) => {
  const {
    email,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    userName,
    backgroundInfo,
    address,
  } = req.body;

  if (
    !email
    || !firstName
    || !lastName
    || !userName
    || !backgroundInfo
    || isEmpty(address)
  ) return res.status(400).json({ err: “You must include all required fields to create a new user!” }); // checking if the req.body contains all the required user fields

  try {
    const emailTaken = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (emailTaken) return res.status(400).json({ err: “That email is already in use!" }); // checking if the user exists before creation

    await User.createUser(req.body); // createUser is a custom static method placed on the model

    res
      .status(201)
      .json({ message: `Successfully created ${req.body.userName}.` });
  } catch (err) {
    const errString = err.toString();

    if (errString.includes("E11000")) return res.status(400).json({ err: “That email is already in use!" }); // handling the error Mongo throws if the user exists during creation

    return res.status(400).json({ err: errString }); // handling any other misc errors
  }
};
```

---

By default `axios` won't return any error from a server. Instead, you're going to have to create a custom `axios` configuration: [axiosConfig.js](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/client/src/utils/axiosConfig.js).  The most important part of this configuration is changing the error `interceptor` as shown [here](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/client/src/utils/axiosConfig.js#L11-L15). This is specifically looking for an error to come from `error.response.data.err`. If you don't use `err` for the API, then you need to update this [line](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/client/src/utils/axiosConfig.js#L12).

The purpose of this [line](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/client/src/utils/axiosConfig.js#L12) is to check if `error.response.data.err` exists, if it doesn't, then it returns a generic `Network Error` (`error.message`) message.

Once you've created this configuration, you'll now need to use it for the entire application (`import axios from '../path/to/axiosConfig'`).

**NOTE**: Please update the [baseURL](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/client/src/utils/axiosConfig.js#L6) to your API `localhost` and it's `port`. The upside to using this configuration is that any calls you make with `axios` will be prepended with `http://localhost:port/`.

For example, instead of:

`axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/user")`

it'll be:

`axios.get("user")`

If you have questions, before asking, please refer to the github repo above as it shows how to integrate everything. If you plan on using this in production, then you'll need to use [ENVs](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/fullstack-mern-kit/blob/master/package.json#L38-L47) (this example utilizes the [better-npm-run](https://github.com/benoror/better-npm-run#readme) package, but you can use [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env#readme) or [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#readme)).

Comment: Thanks @Matt Carlotta for your detailed reply. I applied your solution but I am getting error. I updated my question. You could see there. Thanks.

Comment: If you're using `axios`, then you'll need a custom `axios` configuration to alter the `interceptor`. It, unfortunately, defaults to spitting out a generic error instead of the error returned by the server. Nevertheless, I've updated the answer to include how to accomplish this (located at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks @Matt Carlotta for your detailed reply. Can I use your example like this ?  https://github.com/afoysal/mern/blob/master/client/src/store/actions/addressActions.js

Comment: You can, but it's better to separate it from your `actions` if you plan on reusing the `axios` configuration in other `components` and/or `actions`. Otherwise, it's fine as is.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Carlotta. Your solution is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you look at the `Error` object being logged, you can observe some stuff like `code` property.

You could evaluate such property and if that's the case just pass an appropiate custom error message.

```
address.save()
.then(address => {
   //other code
})
.catch(err => {
   const {code} = err
   console.log(err);
   if (code === 11000) {
     err = new Error('Email already Exists');
   }
   res.status(500).json({
     message: 'Error Occured',
     error: err
   });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @diegoaguilar. But is it possible to modify `'E11000 duplicate key error collection: addresses.addresses index: email_1 dup key: { : "nowphp@yahoo.com" }',
[0]   [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }` ?

Comment: Thanks @diegoaguilar. Your Solution is not working. I am getting `Error: "Request failed with status code 500"` in console. Thanks.

Comment: It's kind of how you are catching and logging the error. Look at the network details

Comment: Thanks @diegoaguilar for your comment. I updated my question.